# Swift: Read and write binary data (cookies) to disk?

Tags: file, swift, cookies, binaryfiles, disk

Specifically I want the command line utility to write the data from `NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies` to a file and then read the data so I can later call `NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().setCookie()`

Here's the code I have so far.

```
if (Process.arguments.count >= 2 && Process.arguments[1] == "-deleteAll") {
    for cookie in NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies! {
        NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().deleteCookie(cookie as NSHTTPCookie)
    }

} else if (Process.arguments.count >= 3 && Process.arguments[1] == "-restore") {
    println("restore from file: " + Process.arguments[2])

} else if (Process.arguments.count >= 3 && Process.arguments[1] == "-export") {
    println("export to file: " + Process.arguments[2])
}
```

The lines

```
for cookie in NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies! {
    cookie.writeToFile("/Users/aaron/Documents/test.txt", options: nil, error: nil)
}
```

give me an error:

```
2014-12-30 20:20:46.564 Test[17423:424845] -[NSHTTPCookie writeToFile:options:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100511260
2014-12-30 20:20:46.579 Test[17423:424845] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSHTTPCookie writeToFile:options:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100511260'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff950fc64c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff97e556de objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff950ff6bd -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff95046a84 ___forwarding___ + 1028
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff950465f8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Test                                0x00000001001caa1f top_level_code + 991
    6   Test                                0x00000001001caa9a main + 42
    7   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff918fd5c9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I guess this is under the category of writing generic data to disk.

Comment: How about the rest of the error message?  It will tell you the  class of the message recipient, that might give you more clues.

Comment: Also might be useful to see the code actually generating the exception since nowhere does your listed code invoke writeToFile...

Comment: @David Hopefully it's clearer now...